# Lambda beta-reductions

Tags: lambda-calculus

I am trying to build a parser for lambda expressions. I have implemented a capture-avoiding substitution using the algorithm below ($e[d/x]$ means replace $x$ by $d$ in $e$)

> $x[d/x] = d$
>
> $y[d/x] = y$ if $x\neq y$
>
> $(e_1 e_2)[d/x] = (e_1[d/x) (e_2[d/x])$
>
> $(\lambda x.e')[d/x] = \lambda x.e'$
>
> $(\lambda y.e')[d/x] = \lambda y.(e'[d/x])$ if $x\neq y$ and $y\notin free(d)$
>
> $(\lambda y.e')[d/x]= \lambda z.(e'\{z/y\}[d/x])$ if $x\neq y$ and $y\in free(d)$ and $z$ fresh

We also know that $(\lambda x. e)(d) = e[d/x]$, so let's use this algorithm to evaluate $(\lambda x.\lambda y.x)(\lambda y.y)$:

$\begin{align*}
(\lambda x.\lambda y. x)(\lambda y.y) & = (\lambda y.x)[\lambda y.y/x] =& \text{(case 5)}\\
& = \lambda y.(x[\lambda y.y/x])= & \text{(case 1)}\\
&=\lambda y.\lambda y.y
\end{align*}$

Where did I go wrong? In particular, I think case 5 should somehow become case 6, but I don't understand why, since $y$ is bounded in $\lambda y.y$.

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: I just re-read the book, maybe because I need to run an alpha-reduction on the argument prior to runing the beta-reduction on the entire thing?

Comment: I did not ask what you did wrong, but why you think that the result you obtained is not the right one. It seems quite alright to me: $\lambda y.\lambda y.y$ is $\alpha$-equivalent to $\lambda y. \lambda z.z$ after all.

Comment: To add on @Nathaniel's answer, your solution is correct but it might confuse you because you are using the same name for different instantiations of variables. You might want to introduce another procedure that starts by assigning each variable appearing in a $\lambda x.$ term a different name to avoid this.